# MVC Model binding on multiple edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following view model

```
public class ResourceProjectedCapacitiesModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public decimal Capacity { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

In my GET action i display all these in the view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List ResourceProjectedCapacitiesModel> list)
{
    foreach (ResourceProjectedCapacitiesModel item in list)
    {
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

In the view there is the following editor but when the form is submitted the binding doesnt work, list is null

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Capacity)
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID)
```

---

```
    @model List<CapacityPlanner.ViewModels.ResourceProjectedCapacitiesModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Last Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Location
        </th>
        <th>
            Manager
        </th>
        <th>
            Role
        </th>
        <th>
            Project
        </th>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <th>Jul</th>
        <th>Aug</th>
        <th>Sep</th>
        <th>Oct</th>
        <th>Nov</th>
        <th>Dec</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manager)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project)
            </td>
            @for(var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                <td>
                    @if(item.Date.Month == i)
                    {
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Capacity)
                    }

                </td>
            }
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" /> 
}
```

I have inserted the code of my view

Comment: Can you please add the entire code of your view? Incl. the `@model` defenition and `foreach` loop. This will help a lot in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: How would you expect to send a single model to a view, but get back a list?  That doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Am I the only one not making sense of this?

Comment: Can you show two `TR`s of the rendred HTML? I have a feeling the `name` properties are not getting rendered correctly.

Comment: You can also look at this post by Scott Hsnselman to get a little insight on how the model binder reads `POST` data: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx I always go back to this when having issues with model binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use for instead of foreach.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
{
 @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Items[i].Amount)
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Items[i].Amount)
}
```

Then all filled will get different id.

Comment: Why `Model.Items[i].Amount`? Why not just `Model[i].Amount`? The model itself is the list or am I missing something?

Comment: @Elad Lachm That was a fast example. Try add `@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].Item)` foreach filled. Change `@foreach (var item in Model) {` to for.